# Sending data via a WebSocket from a c program to a node-red server

Tags: c, websocket, node-red

I wanted to send data from my C code using libc websocket library to my node-red Server.

the code in c below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *message , server_reply[2000];

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(myIpaddr);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 1880 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected\n");

//Send some data
message = "SensorDataTest";
if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Data Send\n");

//Receive a reply from the server
if( recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("recv failed");
}
puts("Reply received\n");
puts(server_reply);

return 0;
    }
```

The probleme is in Node-red I have to specify the path of the socket for example when I send data from a Javascript code I use this address :

```
ws://myipaddr:1880/pathofsocket.
```

Now what I want to know is how I can add the "pathofsocket" to my c code.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use libwebsocket library for this:  https://libwebsockets.org/

Comment: The code you have posted is using native sockets, not websockets. You can use the TCP in node instead of the Websocket node in Node-RED to work with this code.

Comment: The posted code  does not compile!  Here is an error message from the compiler" *untitled.c:19:36: error: ‘myIpaddr’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘in6_addr’?*   Also, since the parameters to function: `main()` are not used, the compiler outputs two warning messages:  *untitled.c:6:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]*  and *untitled.c:6:27: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]*  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `if( recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("recv failed");
}
puts("Reply received\n");
puts(server_reply);`  1) the function: `read()` does not NUL terminate the input string, so the statement: `puts(server_reply)` results in undefined behavior 2) when the read() fails should NOT be trying to access the input buffer because it contains nothing useful

Comment: regarding: `socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}`  must not continue if the call to `socket()` fails

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc , char *argv[])`  causes the compiler to output to warnings about unused parameters.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: what is "Node-red"

Comment: Hi @user3629249, in my code I use directly my ip address, but when I posted the question I changed it to "myipaddr". and for Node-red is a web programming tool, I generally use it as a web server. https://nodered.org/

Comment: There is no secret about a IP address.  That same IP address is used in many many places in the world.  Post code that cleanly compiles so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: If you do not want to use your own IP address, then use: 1) gethostname() : The gethostname function retrieves the standard host name for the local computer.

2) gethostbyname() : The gethostbyname function retrieves host information corresponding to a host name from a host database.

3) inet_ntoa() : The inet_ntoa function converts an (Ipv4) Internet network address into an ASCII string in Internet standard dotted-decimal format.

Comment: Note: the returned value from `read()` says how many bytes were read so that value (which the posted code failed to retain)  can be used to append a NUL byte to the read data